# Child of a "flex: 1" parent and a "min-height" grand-parent not taking "width: 100%"

Tags: html, css

I need to have a footer hidden just after the bottom of the screen, and be able to use the entire flex-grown remaining height for the content children, without inheriting max-height all the way down, is it possible?

Here "Grand child" isn't taking the entire height :

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: lightseagreen;
}

main {
  /* pushes the footer just after the bottom */
  min-height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content-child {
  flex: 1;
}

.content-grand-child {
  height: 100%;
}

footer {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: darkslategray;
}

/* added by editor for demonstration purpose */
.content-child,
.content-grand-child {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 4px solid;
}

.content-child {
  border-color: red;
}

.content-grand-child {
  border-color: green;
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<main>
  <div class="content-child">
    <div class="content-grand-child">Grand child</div>
  </div>
</main>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Is there a better solution to achieve this?

Comment: you mean the element `header` + `main` should have a total height of 100vh by default so that the `footer` is hidden until you scroll down?

Comment: header + main inside an 100vh of height container, then flex and flex-grow : https://jsfiddle.net/ge51bswz/ .. no matter the height of header nor footer anymore that way, flex does the job itself ;)

Comment: Thanks but this means using the combo "display: flex" + "flex-direction: column" + "flex-grow: 1" all the way down, in each of the inner children (I could have many levels of boxes)

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the `<header>` and `<main>` in a `container` and apply the same flex-rules to it with a `min-height: 100vh;` that way, the header's height can be responsive/have an unknown height:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

header {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: lightseagreen;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.content-child {
  flex: 1;
}

.content-grand-child {
  height: 100%;
}

footer {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: darkslategray;
}


/* added by editor for demonstration purpose */

.content-child,
.content-grand-child {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px solid;
}

.content-child {
  border-color: red;
}

.content-grand-child {
  border-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>Header</header>
  <main>
    <div class="content-child">
      <div class="content-grand-child">Grand child</div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks but when I run your code snippet (at least with Chrome), grand child isn't taking "height: 100%"

Comment: @llamnoth which version of chrome / which OS ? for me it works fine and this is basic flex behavior , it should work anywhere nowdays ;)

Comment: if you want to grow the grandchilds height to fill the parent use the same flex rules that you sued befor. you can nest flexboxes in flexboxes...

Comment: The problem seems to be the use of the min-height property, when the child flex item grows, it seems that the height property is not set because only the min-height was set, then "height: 100%" is not working (I'm on a Mac, the Grand child green box of the snippet is not taking 100% of the height, neither on Chrome nor on Firefox)